# Vector is not pushing back

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that translates a string into pig latin. The problem is that the program stops running when I run it. I think the issue is that the vector "sary" is not pushing back. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char alfa[5]={'a','e','i','o','u'};

void vowDet(vector <string> vec, int ary[5], vector <char> sary){
for(int a=0;a<vec.size();a++){
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
if(vec[a].find(alfa[i])!=string::npos){
    ary[i]=vec[a].find_first_of(alfa[i]);
}
else{ary[i]=1000;}
}
int hold;
for(int b=0;b<4;b++){
for(int c=b+1;c<5;c++){
    if(ary[b]>ary[c]){
        hold=ary[b];
        ary[b]=ary[c];
        ary[c]=hold;
        }
    }
}
sary.push_back(vec[a][ary[0]]); //possible source of error
}
}

int main(){
vector <string> vec (0);
string phrase,temp;
vector <char> sary (0);
cout<<"Enter a phrase to translate: ";
getline(cin,phrase);
phrase.push_back(' ');

int ary[5]={1000,1000,1000,1000,1000};
int count=0; 
do{
vec.resize(count+1);
temp=phrase.substr(0,phrase.find(" "));
vec[count].append(temp);
phrase.erase(0,phrase.find(" ")+1);
count++;
}while(phrase.find(" ")!=string::npos);

vowDet(vec,ary,sary);

for(int a=0;a<vec.size();a++){
for(int l=0;l<5;l++){
    if(vec[a][0]==alfa[l]){
        vec[a].append("way");
        goto end;
    }
}
int solve;
for(int g=0;g<5;g++){
    if(sary[a]==alfa[g]){
    solve=g;
    }
}

if(vec[a].find(alfa[solve])!=string::npos){
    temp=vec[a].substr(0,vec[a].find(alfa[solve]));
    vec[a].append(temp);
    vec[a].erase(0,vec[a].find(alfa[solve]));
}
vec[a].append("ay");
end:
cout<<endl<<vec[a]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"The problem is that the program stops running when I run it"_ what

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He's talking about a segmentation fault. I ran the program locally, and it's crashing due to a segfault.

Comment: Just as a general comment... there is a lot of iteration in this code that relies on hard numbers of items in arrays...   i.e... 

`for(int b=0;b<4;b++){`
`for(int c=b+1;c<5;c++){`

How do you know that whatever you're using b and c to index has that many items in it, and more than zero items.  This seems like a bit of a recipe for running off the end of one of your arrays.  Hard numbers like this make me a little squeamish in general.

Comment: @jwir3: That's great but my point is that this detail must be _in the question_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, I totally agree. I was simply trying to clarify for those reading the question until if/when the author decided to add that detail to the question itself, so that others didn't have to compile it to determine the problem he/she was facing.

Comment: If you're going to post code like this, at least post it formatted correctly.

Comment: Not that you were asking for a code review exactly, but: This program is really overcomplicated. I was able to write the same thing in 6 lines of code. Please look at `std::rotate` and `std::any_of`. Also, there is no excuse for using `goto` in C++, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `sary` *by value*, the function gets a copy of the caller's vector. Any changes made in the function won't be seen by the caller. Pass it as a reference to get the behavior you want.

Note that you are also passing `vec` *by value* which incurs the cost of making a copy. You can pass `vec` as a *const reference* to avoid copying and make it read-only in the function, preventing it from altering the caller's vector.

```
void vowDet(const vector <string> &vec, int ary[5], vector <char> &sary)
```

Comment: Just as another quick note. The reason that  this is crashing the program (compiling and running this code gives me a segmentation fault) is because when you check to see if `sary[a] == alfa[g]`, you're assuming that `sary` has at least one entry, which it doesn't, since the values weren't pushed to a copy of `sary` that the code outside of `vowDet()` can see.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read/understood the whole code, but that is a possibility. The `vector<char> sary` is passed by value, meaning that when you invoke `vowDet()`, a local copy will be created and any change you make to it will remain local and not affect the original copy from which the local was created. Try passing by reference by changing the declaration to:

```
void vowDet(vector <string> vec, int ary[5], vector <char> &sary)
```